# take string input at 2-d array in c

Tags: c

i am new in c,so i want to input string at 2-d array,but don't print string.what's wrong in this code and how can i fixed this problem.thanks in advanced

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char col[100][100];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            scanf("%s",
                  &col[i][j]);

        }
    }
     for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
           printf("%s\t",col[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show your input and expected output. It is unclear whether you want to collect a multi-dimensional array of `"strings"` or `"char"`. If you just want a 2-rows with 2 chars, then see answers below. If you actually want 2-rows with 2 strings in each row, then add that clarification.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%c` instead of `%s` because `%s` is a identifier of String. What I found in your code is that you said you want string as input but you are taking char by char as a input. I will suggest you to use pointer to take String as a input in 2D char Array.

**Taking String as a input in 2D char Array**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char *s[100];
    char s1[100];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        scanf("%s", s1);
        s[i]=strdup(s1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%s\n", s[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I am doing is that I am taking the input from user in s1 and put that in the 2D char array. By using this method you have put each string in a each row.

Hopefully that help.

Comment: without pointer is it not possible to take input & print strings

Comment: String is a sequence of character when you talking about taking a string as a input you should be able to take whole string as a input without using enter. What you are doing currently is that you press one character and press enter Which is not a good programming practice that's why I suggest you to use pointer.

Comment: thanks  Chandrapal Singh Jhala sir.for your suggestion.allahhapez

Comment: If you find this solution helpful then mark this as a useful answer or If it solves your problem then press on answer accepted

Answer (score 1):

You're printing a char with `%s`. Change instead to `%c`.

```
printf("%c\t", col[i][j]);
```

With `%s` `printf` will print all characters until a `\0` is found and in your case there's none which will lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: her %c print single value.but i want print string like these- color (full word not single char).

Comment: The type of `col[i][j]` is `char` and `j` is increasing by 1 every iteration so it looks like you're reading char by char, not string. What's your input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

In a 2D character-array, each element `col[i][j]` is a character. But , you're taking string and printing string using the `printf` and `scanf` statements. You need to change the following:

```
scanf("%c",&col[i][j]);
```

and

```
printf("%c\t",col[i][j]);
```

Comment: Reading the input using `scanf` with `%s` is not a mistake. with `%s` you probably want to hit the enter after each character. With `%c` you want to read them without any separation and hit enter after the last one.